# r.js fails to compile

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm working on a project which involves many JavaScript files and uses require.js to manage them.

Everything works fine and there are no browsers errors and my code is exactly fine with lintjs (I'm using CoffeeScript). However, when I try to optimize my scripts into one fail, the operation fails. I installed r.js with npm

**Command executed**

```
r.js -o main.js
```

**Error Message**

```
Error: Build file /devl/premiumthemes/wp-content/themes/premiumthemes/views/files/js/main.js is malformed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
    at Function.build.createConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:22611:23)
```

What could be possibly going wrong?

Comment: Is main.js your build file or the main javascript file of your project (which sounds more likely)? Because the r.js compiler takes either some build settings or a build file as arguments.

Comment: @DerekR It's the main file. I don't remember reading that r.js requires a build file. I'll need to check again!

Comment: Try a tool like JSLint or JavaScriptLint to find the offending line. EDIT: Run them on main.js.

Comment: It doesn't require a build file, but it does require some parameters. The point of the build file is to keep all of those parameters in one file so you don't have to re type the settings every time you compile. http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html

Comment: @bvukelic The code is generated with CoffeeScript, so it pass JavaScriptLint.

Comment: @OmarAbid: Are you using any third party javascript libraries that get combined into main.js at build time?

Comment: Read this section in closer detail - http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#basics

Comment: @DerekR Indeed what I needed was a build file. I was confused as I thought r.js will uglify any file and resolve the dependencies. If you post your comment as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimizer for RequireJs, r.js, requires either a build file or some parameters inline detailing the settings to be used (including things like the files or directories to be optimized, the file that comes out, and so on).

More info on r.js optimization can be found at [RequireJS Optimization](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html).

All the different configuration options can be seen in an [example build file](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js) as well

Comment: How can this answer be marked as the right one?? This is just generic information that anyone can google. In addition an "unexpected token" error is rarely related to a missing parameter on the configuration file.

Comment: Read the comment chain on the OP

Comment: Had a similar error to the above `is malformed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`. This answer fixed my issue, because I was able to compare the example build file and found a trailing ";" at the very end of the file. Removing this extra semi-colon fixed my issue.